# Understanding the $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{n}$ for an EM wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I am trying to understand the idea of the EM-waves and the meaning of the $k$ and $n$ vectors and how can I read them from the given E-field.

Let us suppowe we have a E-field in the form of

$$\vec{E} = E_0cos(kz-wt)\hat{x} + E_0sin(kz-wt)\hat{y}$$

$\vec{k}$: wave-vector

$\hat{n}$: polarization of the field

In this case what is the $\vec{k}$ and $\hat{n}$ ?

I thought that $\vec{k} = k\hat{z}$ and $\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{x} + \vec{y}}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: Please name your symbols. The $k$ you are referring to is probably the wave vector. It has the unit $1/length$, so writing $\vec k = z$ is weird on many levels. The $\vec n$ is probably not the refractive index, but the polarisation of the field. Again, please consider the unit and the dimension. But instead of assuming this, it would be great if you could specify these symbols in your question.

Comment: I am really not good at EMT :/

Comment: I understand your notation, but I reckon that your sloppiness is part of the problem. So I suggest you fix your equations: (1) if you have a vector on the LHS, you should use a vector on the RHS. (2) Try to rewrite the equations using more abstract expressions, such as $\vec k = k \vec e_k$, $\sin(\vec k \cdot \vec r - wt)$, and $\vec E = E_0 \vec n$. By doing so, you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{k}$ tells you the direction of propagation while $ \vec{n} $ is the polarization of the wave and tells you the direction of the electric field. Note that in vacuum space $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{n}=0$

In your case, you have that $ \vec{k}=k\hat{z} $ while as you can see fixing z you have a rotating electric field so you don't have a fix $\vec{n}$ but a $ \vec{n}(t)$ that can you write as
$$
\vec{n}(t)= \cos(\omega t) \hat{x}-\sin( \omega t)  \hat{y}
$$
remember that $\vec{n}$ tells you the direction so you must have that
$$
\vec{E}=|\vec{E}| \vec{n}
$$